# How do I avoid an instant onConnected callback while using PlusClient?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have been writing some experimental code to test out how the PlusClient connection flow works. I followed the documentation and was able to get the account chooser to pop up, and the authorization dialog to show, and was able to get access tokens.

That was yesterday.

Today, I am completely unable to get the PlusClient to connect properly. What happens is that on PlusClient.connect(), the connect callback is immediately called with a null bundle. Calling PlusClient.getAccountName() returns null. I tried calling PlusClient.revokeAccessAndDisconnect() and the onAccessRevoked callback is called with a connectionResult with INTERNAL_ERROR as its errorCode.

It is like the Google Play Services thinks it's got a valid token but has forgotten who was logged in. Is there a way to reset Google Play Services so that it doesn't remember the auth tokens for my application anymore? I've tried clearing Google Play Services and Google Services Framework but this has not fixed my isse.

EDIT:

This is actually happening due to my own stupidity. I had started to refactor the scopes property into its own variable, but had not completed the job. I had done the following in code:

```
    final String scopes = Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " 
            + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE + " " 
            + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata";

    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
              .setVisibleActivities("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",                                                            
                   "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
              .setScopes()
              .build();
```

The problem is that there is an overload for setScopes(), but I meant to say setScopes(scopes) instead. This caused the issue I was describing above.

Answer (score 0):

See the edit for evidence of why I should never code while sleepy. I had forgottten to add a parameter to the setScopes method call in the PlusClient.Builder. Not sure why the API would allow this. It should have thrown a nice exception that I could use to track down my typo.